# Use encrypted client certificate to connect to a docker host

Tags: ssl, encryption, docker

I followed this tutorial from Docker to set up a secure way to communicate with a docker daemon : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

But I wanted to use an encrypted client private key instead of the unencrypted one. 
When I tried to launch a docker command (such as "docker ps") I got the error :

> Could not load X509 key pair: crypto/tls: failed to parse private key.
>   Make sure the key is not encrypted.

This message is clear. But why can't I use encrypted client key ? Is there a specific reason docker doesn't allow that ? A security issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the message, this does not seems a limitation of Docker itself, but from the language/lib it uses to provide that functionality (Go and crypto/tls).

So, I don't think there is an easy way to allow you to use encrypted keys.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I pushed an issue in the docker gitHub : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30935

They will treat it as a feature in a future release. Stay tuned !